# React Three js Question canvas camera controll

Tags: reactjs, canvas, camera

I'm currently practicing three.js and have three planets placed with self-rotation.

When I click on a planet, I want the camera to zoom in on the planet gradually and eventually move to another page.

However, I cannot seem to zoom in on the planet even though I have implemented the planet rotation and obtained the coordinates by clicking.

I would like to implement a feature where the camera gradually zooms in on the planet when the planet is clicked, similar to controlling the camera of the canvas with the mouse scroll. Can someone please help me?

I will attach the code below, which includes the camera movement function.

I have divided it into the Planet and App functions,

Planet function

```js
function Planet({ id, size, texture, position, rotationSpeed, handleClick }) {
    const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
    const textureMap = textureLoader.load(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + texture)

    const planetRef = useRef()

    useFrame(({ clock }) => {
        if (planetRef.current) {
            planetRef.current.rotation.y = clock.getElapsedTime() * rotationSpeed
        }
    })

    return (
        <mesh
            position={position}
            ref={planetRef}
            onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, id)}

        >
            <sphereGeometry args={[size, 64, 64]} />
            <meshStandardMaterial map={textureMap} />
        </mesh>
    )
}
```

App function

```js
function App() {
    const [selectedPlanet, setSelectedPlanet] = useState(null)
    const [cameraPosition, setCameraPosition] = useState([0,0,10])

    const planets = [
        {
            id: 0,
            size: 1,
            texture: 'earth.jpeg',
            position: [-6, 0, 0],
            rotationSpeed: 0.5,
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            size: 0.3,
            texture: 'moon.jpeg',
            position: [-5, 2, 0],
            rotationSpeed: 0.2,
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            size: 1,
            texture: 'mars.jpeg',
            position: [2, 4, 0],
            rotationSpeed: 0.7,
        },
    ]

    const cameraRef = useRef()

    const handlePlanetClick = (e, id) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        const planet = e.object
        setSelectedPlanet(id)
        console.log(planet)
        setCameraPosition([planet.position.x, planet.position.y, planet.position.z + 10])
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(cameraRef)
        console.log(cameraPosition)
        if (cameraRef.current !== null && selectedPlanet !== null) {
            cameraRef.current.position.set(cameraPosition.x, cameraPosition.y, cameraPosition.z)
            cameraRef.current.lookAt(planets[selectedPlanet].position[0], planets[selectedPlanet].position[1], planets[selectedPlanet].position[2])
        } else {
            return
        }
    }, [selectedPlanet, cameraPosition, planets])



    return (
        <div className="min-h-full min-w-full">
            <Canvas
                camera={{
                    fov: 75,
                    near: 0.1,
                    far: 1000,
                    aspect: window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
                    position:cameraPosition,
                }}
                onCreated={({ gl }) => {
                    const controls = new OrbitControls(cameraRef.current, gl.domElement)
                    controls.enableDamping = true
                    controls.maxDistance = 1000
                    controls.minDistance = 0
                    controls.update()
                }}
            >
                <ambientLight />
                <pointLight position={[10, 10, 10]} />
                {planets.map((planet) => (
                    <Planet
                        key={planet.id}
                        id={planet.id}
                        size={planet.size}
                        texture={planet.texture}
                        position={planet.position}
                        rotationSpeed={planet.rotationSpeed}
                        handleClick={handlePlanetClick}
                    />
                ))}
                <perspectiveCamera ref={cameraRef} />
            </Canvas>
        </div>
    )
}
```

but for practice purposes, I have put both functions in one file. The coordinate values are output as follows: [x, y, z].